# Trying to push changes to github repo

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push changes from my local machine to my github repo and it's not working.

I have committed locally:

```
nate@nate-desktop:~/PycharmProjects/TrendFollowing$ git commit -m "Change the underlying data type for time series from a list of dictionary entries to numpy arrays"
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   trendfollowing/breakouts.py
#   modified:   trendfollowing/extrema.py
#   modified:   trendfollowing/test/breakouts_test.py
#   modified:   trendfollowing/test/timeseries_extrema_test.py
#   modified:   trendfollowing/test/timeseries_test.py
#   modified:   trendfollowing/timeseries.py
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Next, I tried (just to be sure):

```
nate@nate-desktop:~/PycharmProjects/TrendFollowing$ git remote add origin git@github.com:natereed/trendfollowing.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

This command was provided by github when I setup the repo (I think).  I created a test project and substituted "test" with the name of my repo:

```
nate@nate-desktop:~/PycharmProjects/TrendFollowing$ git push -u origin master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

Why is it not pushing my changes?

EDITED: Added missing error message ("no changes added to commit")

Comment: Are you sure that the output from your `git commit` didn't end with the following error?  `no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")`

Comment: The answer was already on your screen :-) (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)

Comment: Well actually I had already added all the new files using "git add" - that's why I was confused.  I think it was the removal of a file that had not been added?  Or do I have to run "git add <file>" twice on every file that is added?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't commited. `git commit -m` will only commit what is in the staging area. Either use `git commit -a -m` or use `git add` to add files to the staging area.

Comment: You're right, there were changes that had not been committed because they had not been staged. I used git commit -a -m and that fixed it.

Comment: Is there any difference between "git add <file>; git commit -m" and "commit -a -m"?

Comment: @Nate The -a switch will invoke git add (or rm) on all files that are known to git. This means that if a file is not currently being versioned you wont adding it using `git commit -a` but need to manually add it.